# Lazier way to list type class instances

Tags: isabelle

I do know that I can see all the instances of a type class by using the print_classes command and then scrolling down the alphabetically sorted list of type classes to the desired class. Is there a command which, when provided with a class name, directly shows the instances of this class. (Yes, I do know that this is a first world problem :) )

Answer (score 0):

If by an instance of a class you mean a class that satisfies a subclass relation (e.g. a class that was associated with another class with the command `instance`), then you can view the subclass relationships graphically by using the command `class_deps`. Also, there is a similar command for locales: `locale_deps` (of course, classes are also shown in the diagram that is provided by `locale_deps`).

If by an instance of a class you mean a type that was associated with a particular class by using the command `instantiation`, then you can use the command `print_classes`. As a side remark, there is also a command that enables you to see all interpretations of a given locale. The name of this command is `interpretation`.

As a side note, you can see a list of all standard commands that are available in Isabelle by using the command `print_commands`.

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2020.